# Remote login Amazon (KDP)

Tags: php, curl, amazon-web-services

I'd like to automate the summaries from KDP (Kindle Desktop Publishing). As they don't seem to have any email notification system (at least none that I'm aware of), I need to login via curl. It drives me nuts though. I'm using [simplehtmldom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to retrieve the hidden input values of their login site. The cookies are correct, as are the credentials. Is there something I'm completely missing? $response always gives me the original login site. Consider the following code:

```
function login($url) {
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html($url);
$formarr = array();
$form = $html->find('#ap_signin_form',0);

$formarr["email"] = $this->user;
$formarr["password"] = $this->pass;
foreach ($html->find('#ap_signin_form input[type=hidden]') as $i)
$formarr[$i->name] = $i->value;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $form->action );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $formarr);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->cookie); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );    # required for https urls

$response = curl_exec($ch);
return $response;
}
```

Comment: is it possible it's getting redirected? i know for the KDK site we had to do the same.

Comment: Hi Waynn, thanks four your answer. I'm using CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, additionally I haven't seen any Location-header in curl's verbose output (CURLOPT_VERBOSE). Did you guys manage to remotely login to KDK?

Comment: Yeah, though we're using rails and mechanize. I will say that we did have to turn off SSL verification for ours.

Comment: Analyzing the content, it says that my browser is too old. However, this->agent has the correct value (copied from $_SERVER). Very strange.

Comment: Aren't you missing the CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR option?

Comment: I have tried but it didn't work either.